# MVC.NET 4 Strongly typed view and Checkbox for not binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkboxfor

I was currently building a checkbox list with a strongly typed view when i was stopped by a really odd situation.
So there's my model view:

```
public class QuadroClinicoModelView 
{ 
    public  QuadroClinicoModelView()
    {
        this.check = false;
    }

    public String codigo { set; get; }
    public String nome { set; get; }
    public bool check { set; get; } 
}
```

My list of checkboxes:

```
public List<QuadroClinicoModelView> quadrosClinicos { set; get; }
```

And then in my View:

```
<tbody>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.quadrosClinicos.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.quadrosClinicos[i].check)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.quadrosClinicos[i].codigo)
                @Model.quadrosClinicos[i].codigo
            </td>

    .
    .
    .
</tbody>
```

Everytime i have more than 2 checkboxes in my list all works fine.
But somehow when i have 2 or less checkboxes model view does not bind when i submit the form....

I view the odd kind of form constrution that Microsoft does, with the two different input (hidden and checkbox) with the same name attribute, however when i build  a custom checkbox for with an html helper like:

```
public static class CheckBoxHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString CustomCheckBoxFor(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        string checkBoxWithHidden = htmlHelper.CheckBox(name, htmlAttributes).ToHtmlString().Trim();
        string pureCheckBox = checkBoxWithHidden.Substring(0, checkBoxWithHidden.IndexOf("<input", 1));
        return new MvcHtmlString(pureCheckBox);
    }
    public static MvcHtmlString CustomCheckBoxFor(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name)
    {
        string checkBoxWithHidden = htmlHelper.CheckBox(name).ToHtmlString();
        string pureCheckBox = checkBoxWithHidden.Substring(0, checkBoxWithHidden.IndexOf("<input", 1));
        return new MvcHtmlString(pureCheckBox);
    }
}
```

The Request has the correct value there instead of "true,false" situation, but the model view keep the empty values.
I wanted to avoid to read the values from the request when the model view not bind, is the only workaround i remember.

Can someone help me or seen a problem like i explained above?

Comment: The code in the `for` loop will work fine and will bind correctly. If its not, then its due to some code you have not shown us. And what does your `CustomCheckBoxFor()` have to do with the question - your not using it it your view. Note also your `public QuadroClinicoModelView()` constructor is pointless - the default value of `bool` is already `false`

Comment: The code really works  fine, except when i have 2 or less items on checkbox list. The custom check list it was a solution i read that could correct the problem if it was triggered by the 2 different inputs generated.It was just a solution i tried and did not fix it

Comment: I repeat. The code your have shown **will bind correctly** irrespective of how many items you have in the list (if its not, its because of code you have not shown us).

Comment: I solved the question. I had to distinct checkbox list in my view : **quadrosClinicos** and **quadrosClinicosSelected**, there were to distinct lists there. Somehow the framework messed up with those two similar names, and when i had few items in first list it won't work. I changed the first list to **quadrosToAdd**, and it works. I don't know how but framework doesn't like to checkbox list with similar names.

Comment: If you showed the relevant code, you would probably get an answer to _I don't know how but framework doesn't like to checkbox list with similar names_ :)